# How to write Unit Test for below Exception Handler method using mockito?

Tags: rest, spring-boot, junit, java-8, mockito

```
@ExceptionHandler({ ConstraintViolationException.class })
public ResponseEntity<Object> handleConstraintViolation(ConstraintViolationException ex, WebRequest request) {
    StringBuilder messageBuilder = new StringBuilder("Validation failed for: ");
    ex.getConstraintViolations()
        .stream()
        .forEach(v -> messageBuilder
            .append("property: [" + v.getPropertyPath() + "], value: [" + v.getInvalidValue() + "], constraint: [" + v.getMessage() + "]"));
    return new ResponseEntity<>(responseBuilder
        .createErrorResponse(INVALID_PARAMETER,
            messageBuilder.toString()), getHeaders(), BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

I want to test this @ControllerAdvice method

Comment: You just want to test this method or do you want to test that this ExceptionHandler is used as you expect?

Comment: just want to test that this exception handler are work as expect

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to test the method it suffices to create an instance of `ConstraintViolationException` (your input) and check the output of the `handleConstraintViolation` method applied to it.
You can do somthing like this:

```
ConstraintViolationException exception = mock(ConstraintViolationException.class);
WebRequest webRequest = mock(WebRequest.class); 
YourControllerAdvice controllerAdvice = new YourControllerAdvice();
Set<ConstraintViolation<?>> violations = new HashSet<>();
ConstraintViolation mockedViolation = mock(ConstraintViolation.class);
given(mockedViolation.getPropertyPath()).willReturn("something");
// mock answer to other properties of mockedViolations 
...
violations.add(mockedViolation);  
given(exception.getContraintViolations()).willReturn(violations);

ResponseEntity<Object> response = controllerAdvice.handleContraintViolation(exception, webRequest);

assertThat(response.getStatusCode(), is(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST));
```

plus maybe other assertions on the response body.
However it can be difficult to know how all the different `ConstraintViolationException` instances thrown by spring might look like.

I would instead suggest that you look at MockMvc, which is part of `spring-boot-starter-test`. In this way you can test that the exception handler is used as expected and you can verify the `ResponseEntity` both in the case of constraint violations or not.

```
@WebMvcTest(YourController.class)
public class YourControllerMvcTest {

  @Autowired
  private MockMvc mvc;

  @Test
  public void constraintViolationReturnsBadRequest() throws Exception {
    // Instantiate the DTO that YourController takes in the POST request
    // with an appropriate contraint violation
    InputDto invalidInputDto = new InputDto("bad data");
    MvcResult result = mvc.perform(post("/yourcontrollerurl")
            .content(invalidInputDto)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isBadRequest());

    // assert that the error message is as expected
    assertThat(result.getResponse().getContentAsString(), containsString("default message [must match"));
  } 
}
```

MockMvc has also nice json support so that one can add:

```
.andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.field").value("expected value"))
```

instead of the verifying the response as a string.

Comment: I appreciate your effort but I am using a Mockito framework for testing this method

Comment: look at the updated answer. I still recommend MockMvc since it's bundled with spring boot. Then you don't need mockito for these tests.